# CakePHP: datetime as text

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to insert a datetime using a simple text input (not a datetime input), but there is something wrong.

For example, I'm inserting this date:

```
2015-09-07 15:10
```

My code:

```
debug($this->request->data['created']);
$post = $this->Posts->patchEntity($post, $this->request->data);
debug($post->created);
```

Output:

```
/home/mirko/Server/MeCms_Plugin/src/Controller/Admin/PostsController.php (line 158)
'2015-09-07 15:10'
/home/mirko/Server/MeCms_Plugin/src/Controller/Admin/PostsController.php (line 160)
object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

    'time' => '2013-03-07T15:10:00+0000',
    'timezone' => 'UTC',
    'fixedNowTime' => false

}
```

Why does this happen?
I suspect there is a problem in converting the string into a `Time` object.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you get if you do `$data = $this->request->data ; $data['created'] = new Time($data['created']) ;` and you `patchEntity` with `$data`? (Don't forget to add `use Cake\I18n\Time;`.

Comment: Hi @Holt, this works. Why?

Comment: Are you patching a new, empty entity, or one that holds existing data? If it's the latter, then have you made sure that the value is actually being changed? ie, that what you're debugging there isn't the already existing value? In case the value actually is being changed, or set in an empty entity, I'd suggest to dig into `\Cake\Database\Type\DateTimeType::marshal()` and debug where exactly the date changes.

Answer (score -3):

Look in your Mysql table the `data type` 
ex: change DATE to VARCHAR(50)

Or try this code :

```
$date = new DateTime($post->created);
$srt_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```